# jQuery: Add class to tab & stop going to top of window on click

Tags: jquery

I have 2 issues with my tabbed content.

1.How would I highlight the current tab using my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/FznTg/2/

2.I've added return false, but it still goes to the top of the page when you click a menu item (To see this, resize the viewing window and click a tab.

again: http://jsfiddle.net/FznTg/2/

Really do hope someone can assist.

Comment: It's working now! I'm sure it will be up forever, I can post solution once it's done, no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the scrolling issue by putting the `.show()` or new content before the `.hide()` of old content.  This keeps the document from ever being so small that scrolling is not needed, thus resetting the scroll position.

So, put it in this order:

```
     //fix
     if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3) == "6.0") {
         jQuery('.tabcontent#' + stringref).show();
     } else {
         //display our tab fading it in
         jQuery('.tabcontent#' + stringref).fadeIn();
     }    

     //hide the tabs that doesn't match the ID
     jQuery('.tabcontent:not(#'+stringref+')').hide();
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/E8Jgd/

For setting the style of the current tab, you should just add a class to the current tab which you can then style using CSS.  Putting this line in your click handler will set the current tab to have a class="current" and remove that class from any other tabs:

```
jQuery(this).closest("li").addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
```

You can then style it with CSS like this:

```
.hometabs li.current a {color:red;}
```

And, you can than add the class to the HTML for the first tab by default:

```
<li class="current"><a href="#tab1">All</a></li>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/E8Jgd/

Comment: Added solution for both issues now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/FznTg/3/